# fatest way to know if there is common items between 2 lists in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, optimization, bigdata

I'm currently working on 2 Pandas DataFrame on python. I have a big DataFrame (**135000 Observations**) and I m struggling to find an optimized algorithm that would allow me to perform the calculus more efficiently. My first Database `df` is from food products with for every observation a `list` in the column `df.additives`. It contains  all additives inside the product. Example:

```
df.additives[0]=['milkfat-and-nonfat-milk','e200','and-nonfat-milk','milk','natural-flavor','flavor','mono-diglycerides','diglycerides','guar-gum','e412']
```

The second dataframe is the list of every additive that are unhealthy and they are contained in a list called

```
high=['e202', 'e407', 'e450', 'e250', 'e341', 'e211', 'e621', 'e200', 'e452', 'e481', 'e340', 'e223', 'e451', 'e338', 'e220', 'e252', 'e339', 'e212', 'e224', 'e491', 'e222', 'e251', 'e407a', 'e492', 'e221', 'e473', 'e210', 'e343', 'e482', 'e228', 'e155', 'e243', 'e226', 'e494', 'e459', 'e493', 'e213']
```

My goal is to know if one `element` of `df.additives[i]` matches with  the list `high`. If it's `True` I assigne to the row the value `1` in a dummy column called `df.high`. The ultimate goal is to recognize which food product contains unhealthy additives for later analysis (comparaison etc...)
My code is working well for small amount of products, however every time I'm trying to apply it to my complete dataset the code runs infinitely and well above 1 hours for only 10% of my sample (around 10000). I understand that the architecture of my algorith may be not suitable for a `big data` sample. I'm wondering if we could optimize it so that a modern pc could execute this command under 10 minute? Or maybe do I use an under-optimized Strategy?

**Here below is the code that I'm using:**

```
df['high']= np.zeros(len(df)) # create a dummy column with only zeros at first

def common_member(a, b): # define a fct that give True if there is at least one common elelment
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if (a_set & b_set):
        return True 
    else:
        return False
i=0
while i<len(df.additives):
    
    if common_member(df.additives.iloc[i],high)==True:
        df['high'][i]=1 # change the dummy to 1 in the given row
    i=i+1
```

Alternative that works too but is not optimized to big sample:

```
for row in range(len(df.additives)):
    list_row = set(df.additives.iloc[row])
    if (list_row & set(high)):
        df['high'][row]=1
```

I have tried the solution seen on stack overflow for a near problem, however it didn't work for my situation (dummies stay at all at 0):

```
def common_item(l1, l2):
    return list(set(l1) & set(l2))
i=0
while i<len(df.additives):
    if common_item(df.additives.iloc[i],high)==True:
        df['high'][i]=1
    i=i+1
```

**Thanks for your support**.

Comment: One thing that could help: Instead of storing the additives in lists in the column, convert all to sets once and leave them that way. The conversion from list to set is non-trivial, so doing it over and over for your set comparisons is likely adding overhead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly, your problem is that iterating over things in pandas can be very slow. It's possible that the row by row assignment causes pandas to have to clone *the entire dataframe* once per row.

So, let's pull all the values out before iterating over them with `df.additives.values` and see how that goes, and we can just create a new column of booleans along the way.

```
import random
import string
import time

import pandas as pd

start_time = time.time()

high=set(['e202', 'e407', 'e450', 'e250', 'e341', 'e211', 'e621', 'e200', 'e452', 'e481', 'e340', 'e223', 'e451', 'e338', 'e220', 'e252', 'e339', 'e212', 'e224', 'e491', 'e222', 'e251', 'e407a', 'e492', 'e221', 'e473', 'e210', 'e343', 'e482', 'e228', 'e155', 'e243', 'e226', 'e494', 'e459', 'e493', 'e213'])

def make_ingredients():
    return [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=4)) for i in range(1, 100)]

sample_ingredients = make_ingredients()
sample_ingredients.append('e202')

list_of_ingredients = [make_ingredients() for i in range(1, 350000)]
list_of_ingredients.append(sample_ingredients)

checkpoint_time = time.time()
checkpoint_delta = checkpoint_time - start_time
checkpoint_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(checkpoint_delta))
print(f'Time to create junk data: {checkpoint_string}')

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(len(list_of_ingredients)), 'additives': list_of_ingredients})

df["high"] = [len(set(additives).intersection(high)) > 0 for additives in df.additives.values]

print(df)

intersection_delta = time.time() - checkpoint_time
intersection_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(intersection_delta))
print(f'Time to check for intersections: {intersection_string}')
```

On my laptop, this produces:

```
Time to create junk data: 00:01:21
            id                                          additives   high
0            0  [GBI5, 5ZH5, AUSE, GU8C, Z5WJ, NU56, GJ1M, 8EN...  False
1            1  [JPC7, PZ3P, 7PV1, DP6O, 4OZ9, 3UN0, 3116, MXW...  False
2            2  [1RJP, BG6O, PMI9, Y9PD, W9NF, 25A8, QB6C, 490...  False
3            3  [3WCC, 6682, O0BY, JT52, AG8H, 0HKC, VV7N, 5YU...  False
4            4  [ZOGO, 6V4B, NBJZ, 0U93, 0P2G, 8TIH, B15Y, A7I...  False
...        ...                                                ...    ...
349995  349995  [5G6W, QRPL, D3ZH, XIA8, GG8X, H401, 7RU3, 8VY...  False
349996  349996  [ZLJJ, Q8YG, NCE8, ULBT, 6VFU, B24E, EYU5, SM0...  False
349997  349997  [4UJ0, HYD3, UPQ4, 1H8F, 2MKR, LSAM, M7KC, CWF...  False
349998  349998  [LFER, 44CC, 214W, FXU4, 3F4V, UCRD, 8O8F, SBD...  False
349999  349999  [KZJY, 28MA, TDUL, ANBM, SD1A, 69FT, 9TYY, VTF...   True

[350000 rows x 3 columns]
Time to check for intersections: 00:00:03
```

Yes, the work of checking for set intersections takes three seconds. :)

Comment: I have tried your solutions and it worked within the seconds. Thanks for sharing your way! Optimization was not so much taught in my classes :)